# Libgdx ios In-App Purchase

Tags: java, ios, libgdx, in-app-purchase, gdx-pay

I am currently trying to test in-app purchase on my app for iOS but I am not sure if I have done the implementation correctly because when I test on my iOS device the app crashes whenever I tap on buying the product. Here is my code:

Store.java

```
final MyGame game;
final Asset asset;
OrthographicCamera camera;
Vector3 touchPos;
Texture green_heart,cyan_heart,purple_heart,doublefuel,restore;
int life;
long itemTime;
Preferences prefs;
public static final int APPSTORE_UNDEFINED = 0;
public static final int APPSTORE_GOOGLE = 1;
public static final int APPSTORE_OUYA = 2;
public static final int APPSTORE_AMAZON = 3;
public static final int APPSTORE_DESKTOP = 4;
public static int isAppStore = APPSTORE_UNDEFINED;
public final static String cyan_1 = "cyanheart"; //cyanheart
public final static String green_2 = "greenheart"; //greenheart
public final static String purple_3 = "purpleheart"; //purpleheart
public final static String upgrade_fuel = "doublefuel"; //doublefuel
static PlatformResolver m_platformResolver;
public PurchaseManagerConfig purchaseManagerConfig;

public PurchaseObserver purchaseObserver = new PurchaseObserver() {
    @Override
    public void handleRestore (Transaction[] transactions) {
        for (int i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++) {
            if (checkTransaction(transactions[i].getIdentifier(), true) == true) break;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void handleRestoreError (Throwable e) {
        throw new GdxRuntimeException(e);
    }
    @Override
    public void handleInstall () {  }

    @Override
    public void handleInstallError (Throwable e) {
        Gdx.app.log("ERROR", "PurchaseObserver: handleInstallError!: " + e.getMessage());
        throw new GdxRuntimeException(e);
    }
    @Override
    public void handlePurchase (Transaction transaction) {
        checkTransaction(transaction.getIdentifier(), false);
    }
    @Override
    public void handlePurchaseError (Throwable e) { //--- Amazon IAP: this will be called for cancelled
        throw new GdxRuntimeException(e);
    }
    @Override
    public void handlePurchaseCanceled () { //--- will not be called by amazonIAP
    }
};

protected boolean checkTransaction (String ID, boolean isRestore) {
    boolean returnbool = false;

    if (cyan_1.equals(ID)) {
        life += 1;
        prefs.putInteger("LIFE",life);
        prefs.flush();
        //----- put your logic for full version here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        returnbool = true;
    }
    if (green_2.equals(ID)) {
        life += 3;
        prefs.putInteger("LIFE",life);
        prefs.flush();
        //----- put your logic for full version here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        returnbool = true;
    }
    if (purple_3.equals(ID)) {
        life += 10;
        prefs.putInteger("LIFE",life);
        prefs.flush();
        //----- put your logic for full version here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        returnbool = true;
    }
    if (upgrade_fuel.equals(ID)) {
        prefs.putInteger("FUEL",100);
        prefs.flush();
        //----- put your logic for full version here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        returnbool = true;
    }
    return returnbool;
}

public Store(final MyGame game, final Asset asset){
    this.game = game;
    this.asset = asset;
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false,625,280); //(width,height) 625,280
    touchPos = new Vector3();
    game.font3.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    game.font4.setColor(Color.GOLD);
    green_heart = asset.manager.get("greenheart.png",Texture.class);
    purple_heart = asset.manager.get("purpleheart.png",Texture.class);
    cyan_heart = asset.manager.get("cyanheart.png",Texture.class);
    doublefuel = asset.manager.get("doublefuel.png",Texture.class);
    restore = asset.manager.get("restore.png",Texture.class);
    prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("My Preferences");
    life = prefs.getInteger("LIFE",0);
    purchaseManagerConfig = new PurchaseManagerConfig();
    purchaseManagerConfig.addOffer(new Offer().setType(OfferType.CONSUMABLE).setIdentifier(cyan_1));
    purchaseManagerConfig.addOffer(new Offer().setType(OfferType.CONSUMABLE).setIdentifier(green_2));
    purchaseManagerConfig.addOffer(new Offer().setType(OfferType.CONSUMABLE).setIdentifier(purple_3));
    purchaseManagerConfig.addOffer(new Offer().setType(OfferType.ENTITLEMENT).setIdentifier(upgrade_fuel));
}

@Override
public void show() {
    setPlatformResolver(new AppStoreResolver(this));
    getPlatformResolver().installIAP();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.update();
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    game.batch.begin();
    game.batch.draw(MainMenu.background_final, camera.position.x - (camera.viewportWidth / 2), 0);
    game.font3.draw(game.batch, "BACK",4, camera.viewportHeight - 5);
    game.font.draw(game.batch, "1    LIFE",50, camera.viewportHeight/(float)1.5);
    game.font.draw(game.batch, "3    LIFE",195, camera.viewportHeight/(float)1.5);
    game.font.draw(game.batch, "10    LIFE",340, camera.viewportHeight/(float)1.5);
    game.font4.draw(game.batch, "BEST   VALUE",320, camera.viewportHeight/(float)1.35);
    game.font.draw(game.batch, "FOREVER",490, camera.viewportHeight/(float)1.23);
    game.font.draw(game.batch, "DOUBLE",495, camera.viewportHeight/(float)1.35);
    game.font.draw(game.batch, "FUEL",507, camera.viewportHeight/(float)1.5);
    game.batch.draw(cyan_heart,55,camera.viewportHeight/3);
    game.batch.draw(green_heart,200,camera.viewportHeight/3);
    game.batch.draw(purple_heart,350,camera.viewportHeight/3);
    game.batch.draw(doublefuel,500,camera.viewportHeight/3);
    game.batch.draw(restore,(camera.viewportWidth / 2 - restore.getWidth() / 2),camera.viewportHeight/16);
    game.font5.draw(game.batch, "RESTORE",271, camera.viewportHeight/5);
    if(TimeUtils.millis() - itemTime < 1000){
        game.font6.draw(game.batch, "ITEMS   RESTORED",230, camera.viewportHeight/(float) 1.1);
    }
    game.batch.end();
    if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
        touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.input.getY(),0);
        camera.unproject(touchPos);
        if((touchPos.x >= 4 && touchPos.x <= 55) && touchPos.y >= camera.viewportHeight - 18){
            game.setScreen(new MainMenu(game,this.asset));
            dispose();
        }
        if((touchPos.x >= 55 && touchPos.x <= 55 + cyan_heart.getWidth()) && (touchPos.y >= camera.viewportHeight/3 && touchPos.y <= camera.viewportHeight/3 + cyan_heart.getHeight())){
            getPlatformResolver().requestPurchase(cyan_1);
        }
        if((touchPos.x >= 200 && touchPos.x <= 200 + green_heart.getWidth()) && (touchPos.y >= camera.viewportHeight/3 && touchPos.y <= camera.viewportHeight/3 + green_heart.getHeight())){
            getPlatformResolver().requestPurchase(green_2);
        }
        if((touchPos.x >= 350 && touchPos.x <= 350 + purple_heart.getWidth()) && (touchPos.y >= camera.viewportHeight/3 && touchPos.y <= camera.viewportHeight/3 + purple_heart.getHeight())){
            getPlatformResolver().requestPurchase(purple_3);
        }
        if((touchPos.x >= 500 && touchPos.x <= 500 + doublefuel.getWidth()) && (touchPos.y >= camera.viewportHeight/3 && touchPos.y <= camera.viewportHeight/3 + doublefuel.getHeight())){
            getPlatformResolver().requestPurchase(upgrade_fuel);
        }
        if((touchPos.x >= (camera.viewportWidth / 2 - restore.getWidth() / 2) && touchPos.x <= (camera.viewportWidth / 2 - restore.getWidth() / 2) + restore.getWidth()) && (touchPos.y >= camera.viewportHeight/16 && touchPos.y <= camera.viewportHeight/16 + restore.getHeight())){
            itemTime = TimeUtils.millis();
            getPlatformResolver().requestPurchaseRestore();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    getPlatformResolver().dispose();

}

public static PlatformResolver getPlatformResolver() {
    return m_platformResolver;
}
public static void setPlatformResolver (PlatformResolver platformResolver) {
    m_platformResolver = platformResolver;
}

public int getAppStore () {
    return isAppStore;
}
public void setAppStore (int isAppStore) {
    this.isAppStore = isAppStore;
}
```

}

AppStoreResolver.java

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.pay.PurchaseManagerConfig;


public class AppStoreResolver extends PlatformResolver {

private final static String APPLEKEY  = "......";


static final int RC_REQUEST = 10001;    // (arbitrary) request code for the purchase flow

public AppStoreResolver(Store game) {
    super(game);

    PurchaseManagerConfig config = game.purchaseManagerConfig;
    config.addStoreParam(PurchaseManagerConfig.STORE_NAME_IOS_APPLE, APPLEKEY);
    initializeIAP(null, game.purchaseObserver, config);
}}
```

Here is my log on xcode when I tap on in-app products in my game:

```
gdx-pay 4 initializeIAP(): purchaseManager == null => call 
PurchaseSystem.hasManager()
IAP 4 IAP: gdx-pay successfully instantiated.
gdx-pay 4 calls PurchaseSystem.install() via reflection
[GdxPay/AppleIOS] Installing purchase observer...
[GdxPay/AppleIOS] Requesting products...
gdx-pay 4 installed manager: AppleiOS
[GdxPay/AppleIOS] 0 products successfully received
[GdxPay/AppleIOS] Invalid product received, purpleheart
[GdxPay/AppleIOS] Invalid product received, greenheart
[GdxPay/AppleIOS] Invalid product received, doublefuel
[GdxPay/AppleIOS] Invalid product received, cyanheart
[GdxPay/AppleIOS] Purchase observer successfully installed!
[GdxPay/AppleIOS] There are 0 unfinished transactions. Try to 
finish...
art I  5041 733097 /Users/rolandvigh/Migeran-
1.3/aosp/art/runtime/gc/heap.cc:2729] Background sticky concurrent 
mark sweep GC freed 46610(1434KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS 
objects, 58% free, 1595KB/3MB, paused 10.712ms total 124.734ms
[GdxPay/AppleIOS] Requesting product info for cyanheart
gdx-pay 4 calls purchasemanager.purchase()
[GdxPay/AppleIOS] Error purchasing product (wrong product info count 
returned: 0)!
2018-03-02 14:43:18.738 MyGame[5041:732911] *** Terminating app due 
to 
uncaught exception 'com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException', 
reason: 
'com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Error purchasing product (wrong product info count returned: 0)!
at com.robot1games.game.Store$1.handlePurchaseError(Store.java:70)
at com.badlogic.gdx.pay.ios.apple.PurchaseManageriOSApple$AppleProductsDelegatePurchase.productsRequestDidReceiveResponse(PurchaseManageriOSApple.java:319)
at apple.uikit.c.UIKit.UIApplicationMain(Native Method)
at com.robot1games.game.IOSMoeLauncher.main(IOSMoeLauncher.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error purchasing product 
(wrong product info count returned: 0)!
... 3 more'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x218af91b 0x2104ae17 0x403219f 0x4038175 0x4041619 0x403f0a4 
0x475fb7f 0x475fb6b 0x4764655 0x21871b6d 0x21870067 0x217bf229 
0x217bf015 0x22dafac9 0x25e93189 0x403f01c 0x40412d5 0x403a103 
0x403a033 0x403ab9b 0x4041619 0x403f0a4 0x3d52851 0x3da1117 0x3da0f0f 
0x3e606e5 0x3bffe73 0x3f22b25 0x3aff319 0x174a25 0x21467873)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type 
ObjCException
(lldb)
```

PS: Also do I need to add any swift class for IAP handling in the xcode, if yes, how do I do it on this Libgdx project.

Comment: No swift class should be needed. An error log would be nice if you want more help

Comment: Okay, I have already added the log, but I still have a feeling that I did not do the IAP implementation correctly in my AppStoreResolver.java class.

Comment: Does anyone know why do I have an error?

Comment: What is your IDE? Is it Android Studio?

Comment: I am using Android Studio to develop but using Xcode to test on the iOS platform.

Answer (score 0):

Your app crashes beacuause of throwing exception - line 70 of Store.java:

```
throw new GdxRuntimeException(e);
```

Did you setup all in-app purchases correctly? Here is also info how to test your in app purchases with a test user: https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/203809008-iOS-How-to-Test-In-App-Purchases-in-Your-App

And it is no need to add any of swift class

Comment: Thank you, i'll check the link out sometime soon, but is there any way I can check the error log on Android Studio while connecting and testing on my iOS device?